# Passing different args in Kubernetes after creation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I wanted to know if it was possible to pass different args in Kubernetes deployment after creation?

I have this repo setup but it requires deploying twice. Once when creating the pods and another for restarting. I cannot use the same deployment I used to create the pods due to specific args that are being passed.

Is it possible to pass specific args the first time a deployment is applied and then another set of args afterwards?

This is the repo: https://github.com/InterestingSoup/urbit-k3s-rpi

You can see that it requires `urbit -w <my-planet> -k <my-key-file>` when you first deploy.

But then to continue using it, or when the pod is restarted, these are the args that are needed `urbit <my-planet or my-comet>`

I cannot use the same args as first deploy because then the agent won’t boot.

Any Kubernetes tips or tricks to make this possible?

Comment: Instead of error out, can your program just exit upon bootstrap?

Comment: When you set `replicas: 3` on the initial deployment, what should happen?  What if the cluster needs to delete and recreate a pod on its own?  I might look at restructuring my application to avoid this setup and initialize the state some other way.